# Tableau Stacked Bar Chart Bar Colors

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in Tableau. Each bar is colored as numerical (Red lowest value and blue highest value), but I want each column name to resemble a color instead. For example, the bar for hemolytic cum 2020 as red, 2021 as yellow, previous 52 weeks as green, and current week as purple. I filtered the column, "Measure Values," to the four columns already. How do I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put **"Measure Names"** field to the **color mark**, not Measure Values.
Then you can edit the colors :)